# Interacting with large XLSX file on HTML page?

Tags: python, html, css, flask, bootstrap-4

I have a large (6000 columns, 3 rows) XLSX file. Basically, I want users to be able to select a single column based on search results and then pass the selected column into a list. However, I have absolutely no idea where to start. I've looked into bootstrap-select for implementing a live-search function but that's about it. I'm not sure whether a full table would really be the best option, and even if I did that, I don't know it would be interactable.